# How to loop items in struct?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a struct in a class:

```
class ShoppingItems : NSObject
{
    struct historyLists {
        var id: String
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var itemCount: Int
        var date: String
        var img: String
        var marktName: String
        var price: Float
        var productsOnList = [items]()
    }

    struct items {
        var id: String
        var quantity: Int
    }
}
```

Now I append some stuff:

```
var myStructHistoryItemLists = [historyLists]()

myStructHistoryItemLists.append(historyLists(id: "l1", name: "NAME1", description: "DESC1", itemCount: 10, date: "22.02.2014", img: "IMG1", marktName: "marktNAME", price: 22.50, productsOnList: [
        items(id: "p1", quantity: 11),
        items(id: "p2", quantity: 1),
        items(id: "p3", quantity: 5)
    ]
))

myStructHistoryItemLists.append(historyLists(id: "l2", name: "NAME2", description: "DESC2", itemCount: 5, date: "10.01.2017", img: "IMG2", marktName: "marktNAME2", price: 22.50, productsOnList: [
        items(id: "p4", quantity: 11),
        items(id: "p5", quantity: 1),
        items(id: "p6", quantity: 5),
        items(id: "s1", quantity: 5)
    ]
))
```

My question is how can I append the items in a loop from an array?

```
myStructHistoryItemLists.append(historyLists(id: "l3", name: "NAME3", description: "DESC3", itemCount: otherItemsArray.count, date: "10.01.2017", img: "IMG3", marktName: "marktNAME3", price: 22.50, productsOnList: [
        for items in otherItemsArray ....
        items(id: otherItemsArray[item].id, quantity: otherItemsArray[item].quantity),
    ]
))
```

And how can I access this from another class?

Thanks

Comment: Create the items array before you call myStructHistoryItemLists.append(...). then just assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `otherItemsArray` is an array of `items`, then all you need to do is to pass your array for the `productsOnList` parameter.

```
let historyList = historyLists(
    id: "l3", name: "NAME3",
    description: "DESC3",
    itemCount: otherItemsArray.count,
    date: "10.01.2017", img: "IMG3",
    marktName: "marktNAME3",
    price: 22.50,
    productsOnList: otherItemsArray
)
myStructHistoryItemLists.append(historyList)
```

Also the way you name your structs is wrong. They should be singular and start with an uppercase letter (`HistoryList` and `Item`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Its so damn easy ;) (thx, i will rename the structs!)